# Wordpress - my query string is getting stripped out

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

When landing on my wordpress site with a FB tracking query string such as

```
?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=something+else+foo
```

The string always gets cut down to

```
?+else+foo
```

I have Yoast SEO installed and can't find a setting that might be affecting this. From the research I've done, can't seem to find the exact reason, possibly a .htaccess issue.

Any help would be appreciated - even just pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the rewrite rules :)

Answer (score 0):

You are having a space in the string please remove that space and add "-" or "_" between word.